# Как Python обрабатывать видео? Рандомизировать, менять цветокоррекцию и т.д

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, видео

На входе есть видео. Есть задача рандомизировать (сделать видео немного отличное от исходного), сменить цветокоррекцию, гамму, обрезать видео и другие параметры. Очень простые функции как в Sony Vegas Pro.

Или может есть способ и примеры работ взаимодействия Sony Vegas Pro и Python?

Comment: Наверное тебе надо подключить https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenShot_Video_Editor как библиотеку.

Comment: https://www.hlinke.de/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:vegas_python_dev